# Google Dart AJAX and MVP capabilities vs what GWT offers

Tags: java, gwt, dart, mvp, single-page-application

I am thinking of learning Google [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) for client-side development but have some concerns that I don't see addressed on their site or their developer forums:

1. I see that the *dart2js* cross-compiler has a `-minify` option for outputting minified JS, but what about **obfuscated** JS, like what GWT does?
2. Does Dart have AJAX capabilities, and if so, can I use AJAX to communicate with a Java-based (servlets) backend?
3. Does Dart have WebSockets/comet/server-push capabilities, so if I need to update the UI with a message from the server (asynchronously), I can?
4. Does Dart have MVC/MVP frameworks available (either built-in or via 3rd party libs)?
5. Does Dart have navigation/history management frameworks available (either built-in or via 3rd party libs)? Something similar to GWT's [**Activities & Places**](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) framework?
6. Can Google Dart interface with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 2):

1. minify already obfuscated
2. sure, you can , refer [dart api](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#httpRequest)
3. you can find web socket library in [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_socket_server#pub)
4. if you need production quality, angular is more mature than polymer right now, but polymer may catch up soon
5. I use polymer, but you can rely on built-in [history api](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/History.html#api)
6. phone gap can be interface by dart-js

Comment: Thanks @kao peter (+1) - however all of your links seem to be broken or not working! Can you check them and update them when you get a chance? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1. not heard of obfuscation for Dart but minified JS seems very obfuscated too
2. of course. Using REST web services with JSON as data format or Protocol Buffers accessing services is easy
3. not sure about this. WebSockets are supported AFAIK
4. Angular.Dart or to some extend Polymer
5. I think [route_hierarchical](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route_hierarchical) does this. Building my own using window.pushState was easy too
6. What I heard some were successful doing so but I'm not sure about.

Comment: Thanks @zoechi (+1) - can I use **both** polymer.dart and angular.dart in the same project? Or do you have to choose one or the other? Thanks again!

Comment: I found [Do dart polymer and angular.dart play nicely together?](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web-ui/nxSxuZe9-FU)